# Push Mow Around Pine Island

Tags: grass, mowing

I have a push mower (two wheels on the front and two on the back). When I mow around my circular pine or mulch islands [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mAoy.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mJBR.png), a wheel inevitably falls into the island and buzzes my grass, leaving streaks of brown. I like keeping the grass pretty short if I can. I have resorted to using a weed eater to trim the grass around the islands, but it is hard work. Any tips (ideally not requiring a new mower)?

You can see the brown streak in the top image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mAoy.png).

[image: Island]

[image: Island]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the pine island, please?

Comment: @Jurp Good idea. Done. This one is a mulch island. Maybe filling in the mulch would help keep the mower level? I tend to send the mulch flying whenever I edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Fill in (or rake back after edging) the mulch should work.
- Provide a hard edge that won't go flying (such as bricks or pavers) for the mower wheel to ride on should work.
- Cut the grass higher (which lets it put down deeper roots, too, so it's healthier and more drought-resistant) should
  work, but you don't like that.
- A different mower you don't want to buy now that has more overhang beyond
  the wheel track would work. So when this one dies, give that a thought when replacing it.

*Why nobody seems to make a mower with selectable string trimmers mounted on either side is beyond me, as it seems like it would be handy to a lot of users, and a great sales gimmick.*

Comment: What a creative idea. / I doubt the push mower will ever die.

Comment: All great ideas. Thank you. I didn't realize the other benefits to cutting it higher so I will consider that too.